# Is there an optimal time to use nitrous?

Tags: the-crew

I can use nitrous to boost the speed of my car, but I seemed to notice it sometimes affect the speed more, sometimes less. Is there an optimal time to use it for greatest benefit or is it all just in my tired head?

Answer (score 1):

It's best to use your nitrous out of corners as it improves your acceleration immensely. Long straights are also a great place to reach your top speed and then some with the help of nitrous.

Your nitrous gauge charges pretty quickly, so don't be stingy!